# how the ping implementation calculating the round trip time?

Tags: c, linux, ping

I was learning about the ping implementation.

In that I had one doubt. The doubt is, how they calculating the round trip time.

They done some calculation to calculate the round trip time. I am not able to understand that calculation.

Here is the code for the round trip time calculation.

```
 tsum += triptime;
 tsum2 += (long long)triptime * (long long)triptime;
 if (triptime < tmin)
      tmin = triptime;
 if (triptime > tmax)
      tmax = triptime;
 if (!rtt)
      rtt = triptime*8;
 else
      rtt += triptime-rtt/8;
```

The tsum, tsum2, triptime, tmax variables are initially 0.
The tmin contains the value as 2147483647 as initially.
The triptime is calculated by the before the packet sending, noted one time. In destination the packet is received, before it send replay it note one time and it fill that in reply packet and it sends the reply.
The two times are subtracted and convert that subtracted time into micro seconds. The triptime variable contains that micro seconds.

For example, take the below output for calculating the rtt.

The trip time for the first packet is 42573, and second packet 43707, third packet 48047, and fourth packet 42559.

Using this how they calculate the round trip time. Why they multiply with 8 in the starting and after that they divide with 8 and subtract with the first rtt. I am not able to find why they calculating the rtt like that.
Can any one please explain me why they multiply with 8 in starting and after that why they divide with 8 and subtract with the before calculated rtt.
The below link contains the full code for the ping implementation.

[ping_common.c](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping_common.c)

[ping.c](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping.c)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it is a way to do an average of la accumulated 8 values. First packet is the initialization of average accumulator (`triptime*8`). After that is added to accumulator only the variation (difference) on the last calculated average.

Comment: BTW as usual for linux mudules: shamelessly lack of comments, every time a everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

`rtt` is [Modified Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Modified_moving_average) of `triptime` values, multiplied by 8 for easy calculations, with `N==8`.

Comment: The formula is something like `RTT_new = RTT_old*7/8 + triptime*1/8`. The `rtt` in your code is `RTT_new*8` to save one division. Look also at [RFC6298](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6298).

Comment: why they multiplied with 8 and  Why not 16 or any other number?

Comment: What is the use of 8 in here?

Comment: @suresh it is an arbitrary number. You should think to this as an array of samples. In this case it is an array of 8 samples.

Comment: Here this is not like an array of samples. I can send n number of packets.  So I can send more than 8 packets or less than 8 packets. So, why they hard coded 8.

Comment: They arbitrarily decided to use N==8, and used a multiplier equal to N for easy calculations.

Answer (score 0):

`rtt` in the program variable name is not necessarily *rtt* in the output - And here it isn't.

The 'average round trip delay' in the implementation you show is in `tsum` / count of packets. When you look at `rtt`, you are actually looking at something different. That is only displayed when you use `ping`in adaptive mode.

Comment: In ping statistics, there is a one field called rtt. In above code they calculating the rtt. I need the answer for what is the formula to calculating the rtt?

Comment: And I just told you that the output of the ping statistics labeled as "rtt" is not the same thing as the variable "rtt"

Answer (score -1):

Because you are dealing with bits. Bit rate and transmission time are not the same thing, so you need to do a tiny bit of arithmetic to convert. The formula is:

> Packet transmission time = Packet size / Bit rate

So assuming 100 Mbit/s and a packet size of 1526 bytes, you get:

> 1526 bytes x 8 bits / (100 x 10<sup>6</sup> bits/second)) = 116 microseconds

The bit unit cancels out and you are left with seconds.

Now here's another example. Say you have a round trip time of 225 milliseconds and your throughput is 32 kilobytes. You get:

> 32,000 bytes * 8 bits / 0.255 = 1,003,921 bits per second

Comment: `ping` is not concerned with transmission rates.

Comment: I did not ask about the transmission rate. Please read the question once again.